# How to pseudo-randomize trials without repeating same condition more than three times

Tags: matlab, random

I know there are lots of pseudo-randomization skills but this one, I couldn't search it so I put it on here.

I am using MATLAB 2018a. I've been trying to set up a behavior experiment which has 10 conditions. Each condition has 50 trials. This results in 500 trials total. 
I would like to pseudo-randomize the sequence of trials such that no same conditions appear more than three times consecutively.

I thought it would be not so difficult since I have many conditions but some of the methods I found by googling had minor problems. One of the methods I used was by extracting indexes using 'unique(find(diff(seq)==0))', re-randomize it and replace it with the original redundant sequence. ([Link](https://kr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/112353-shuffle-vector-with-constraints#answer_120862)) But this method had a problem that it would randomly change the total number of a condition. If you wanted 40 trials for each condition, it would result in 39 for some conditions while 41 for others..

My question would be how to improve this method to have constraints of having no one condition repeated three times, while solving the problem mentioned above.
Or would there be any better ways?

Comment: What if you built the sequence one element at a time in a for loop? You could perform a check if the new random trial is he same as the previous two accepted trials. If you could provide some code of  how you're identifying trials, it would be easier to give a better answer. The part about 40 stimuli is making it difficult to get a clear picture of what you want. What's the difference between a trial and a stimuli?

Comment: I could have provided the code I tried with the method from the link but it was not exactly what I wanted. Sorry for the confusion with the words, I should have clarified what those meant. I edited a bit. I basically meant the same thing above. 10 conditions, 40 questions each. I think I shouldn't have used 'stimuli' instead of trials.

Comment: @Khlick .. and about the idea you suggested, I think we also need to maintain the total number of 'to be selected' trials for each conditions..By the way, thank you for the comment.

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for adding some clarification. Now, I'm not sure what you mean by 'to be selected' trials. Is your setup 10 conditions (C1 to C10) of trials (T1 to T40) such that you might want to have a randomly permuted order of {C1_T1, C3_T39, C10_T2, ... }? I get that you don't want C1_T# three times in a row, but do I have the trial I'd scheme correct?

Comment: I think a short example would do. Let's say I have 3 conditions instead of 10, and I have 4 trials for each condition. The following sequence of numbers mean one of three conditions. 
> what I don't want would be : 2 3 2 3 3 1 1 1 3 2 3 1 2 2 1
> what I want would be : 2 3 2 3 1 3 1 1 3 2 3 1 2 2 1
You can see that in the first sequence, condition 1 is repeated three times in a row. But in the second sequence, there is no such repeat.

Comment: Once the order of the conditions are set like that, I can randomly assign 4 trials for each conditions. C2_t1 C3_ t2 C2_t3 C3_t4 C1_t1 C3_t3 C1_t3 C1_t2... and so on.

Comment: Ok. I think I understand. I'll post a possible solution in a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*disclaimer: this solution is not perfect.*

Ok, so my iterative approach is to create a permuted vector of all possible trials and then append each one to another vector if it doesn't violate the *more than 3 consecutive conditions of the same type*.

First, I'll set up some constants

```matlab
N_CONDITIONS = 5;
TRIALS_PER_CONDITION = [10 10 10 7 9];
N_DUPS_ALLOWED = 3;

N_TOTAL = sum(TRIALS_PER_CONDITION);
```

Then I create a random permutation of all the trials:

```matlab
randomInds = randperm(N_TOTAL);
% make vector containing all the replicates
conditionTrials = repelem(1:N_CONDITIONS, TRIALS_PER_CONDITION);

% permute the conditions
conditionTrials = conditionTrials(randomInds);
```

Then I prepare to loop over the `conditionTrials` vector element by element

```matlab
% initialize the random trials vector
randomizedTrials = zeros(N_TOTAL, 1);

% pre assign the first allowable possible duplications
randomizedTrials(1:N_DUPS_ALLOWED) = conditionTrials(1:N_DUPS_ALLOWED);
% drop the used values
conditionTrials(1:N_DUPS_ALLOWED) = [];
```

Next, I setup the loop variables/counters and perform the loop:

```matlab
% initialize counter
i = N_DUPS_ALLOWED + 1;
iterCounter = 1;
maxIter = 1000; % set me pretty low, but high enough for extra perms
while any(~randomizedTrials)
  iterCounter = iterCounter + 1;
  if iterCounter > maxIter 
    fprintf(2, '\nMaximum interations exceeded.\n');
    break
  end
  % get the value we want to test
  currentTrial = conditionTrials(1);
  % get the previes n_dups_allowed values
  previousConditions = randomizedTrials( i - (N_DUPS_ALLOWED:-1:1) );
  % check if they're the same
  if sum(previousConditions == currentTrial) == N_DUPS_ALLOWED
    % reject this value because last 3 values == currentValue
    % accepting would lead to > 3 consecutive trials
    % create a new shuffle
    newPermInds = randperm(length(conditionTrials));
    conditionTrials = conditionTrials(newPermInds);
    continue
  end
  % accept the random number, insert it in the trails vector
  randomizedTrials(i) = currentTrial;
  % now drop the value
  conditionTrials(1) = [];
  i = i+1;
end
```

The loop essentially states: *%while at least 1 zero present in the randomizedTrials vector, check if the next value violates `N_DUPS_ALLOWED`. If no violation, pop it from the `conditionTrials` vector and append it to the `randomizedTrials` vector. Otherwise, re-permute the trials and try again.*

I also wrote in a check to make sure we don't loop forever... as might be the case if we come toward the end of the vector and we get many replicates.

Comment: Among the coercing iteration approach I've seen on the Internet, I think your code works the best. As far as I know, coercing iterations approach meet problems when the number of conditions are low (like 4) and the allowed number of repeats is also very low (like 2). I tested it with 'N_CONDITIONS = 4' and 'N_DUPS_ALLOWED = 1'. This harsh condition prints out 'Maximum interations exceeded.' about half the time I run it. It works almost everytime for my case ( 'N_CONDITIONS = 10' and 'N_DUPS_ALLOWED = 2'). Thank you for such a great work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to submit a slight modification that gives "better" randomization potentially. Say you want 300 total picks and you have indices between 1 and 500 with every 50 being a new condition. You could set up a system such that you have no more than 2 consecutive conditions but every 10 conditions would all be completely different.

```
cond_num = [];

for ii = 1:30
    cond_num = [cond_num randperm(10)];
end
sample_num = (cond_num-1)*50+randi([0 9],size(cond_num));
```

In this case, you have very few consecutive conditions while having even numbers in each class. If you wish to have no repeated samples this becomes a bit harder but probably manageable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it for myself. I understood how it would turn out. The distribution would be fairly even over 10 different conditions and, although it is not perfectly "random", I think it still works because it is pseudorandomization anyway. Since the different type of the conditions are relatively large for my case(10 instead of 3 or 4), I think I can modify this a bit which I am trying now.

Comment: By the way, I would need 500 out of 500 numbers to be randomized. So, with the last line, ///
sample_num = (cond_num-1)*50+randi([0 9],size(cond_num)); /// I am not 100% sure what this does. Is it that you multiply 50 to make this 300 numbers out of 500 and randomly add 0 to 9 to further induce variability? If this is the case, I think I should only use the for loop and just coerce it to not have any repeates in the joint part of each sequence of 10 numbers by nesting it in a while loop.

Comment: The reason I would do so is that because if I want 500 out of 500 and adopt the method above and set ii = 1:50, I will get numerous overlap of numbers. For example, it would have multiple 1s. I think it works when you need a subset of numbers.